# Position and resize fixed background image to properly fit div

Tags: css, background-image, css-position

I'm trying to fit a **fixed** background image properly into a div.
I want the image to

- have its left edge be positioned on the divs left edge, even if the div is positioned with margin auto
- have a width of exactly the divs size

Both points are problematic.

100% background-size seems to relate to the images original size and not to the div-size. Maybe contain is the correct thing here, but I can't verify that without a solution to problem no 2.

The background-position seems to relate to the complete browser viewport and not to the div.

I have made the image have a proper dimension, so that it should be high enough to cover the visible area when being scrolled over.

Here is a jfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/417u343f/3/
As you can see, the image is starting more to the left than the start of the div and because of that, it's repeating before the div is at its end.

Thanks for any help, I hope I made my problem clear enough.

```
<div class="outer">
  <div class="test">
    <div class="test1">
    </div>
    <div class="test2">
  Text...
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
div.test {
  width: 80%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  height: 250px;
}
div.test1 {
  width: 50%;
  height:100%;
  float:left;

  background-image: url('image...');
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: contain;
}
div.test2 {
  width:50%;
  float:left;
}
```

Comment: Your fiddle and code do not seem to display the problem you're referring to.

Comment: indeed, I'm confused, please try https://jsfiddle.net/417u343f/3/

Comment: Can't see that second one reproduce the described problem either. // _"100% background-size seems to relate to the images original size and not to the div-size"_ - no, it relates to the viewport size, because that becomes _background positioning area_ when background-attachment is `fixed`. Since what the issue is, is still unclear from the examples so far, I don't know if this will come closer to what you want, but try to position the background image `10%` from the left (difference of 100% and 80% div'd by 2), and make the background-size `40%` (50% of the 80%) - that closer to what you want?